# SQL: Move data in one column to different columns

Tags: sql, case

SQL Noob here...I have a SQL query that produced this output. The issue is that one column contains different types of data.  I need to separate them into different columns.

```
NODENAME MIB                STATUS
Node1    CPUTemperature     +27.20 C
Node2    CPUTemperature     +27.00 C
Node3    CPUTemperature     +26.50 C
node4    CPUTemperature     +27.00 C
node5    CPUTemperature     +27.80 C
node1    NiosVersion        6.5.2
node2    NiosVersion        6.5.2
node3    NiosVersion        6.5.2
node4    NiosVersion        6.5.2
node5    NiosVersion        6.5.2
node6    NiosVersion        6.5.2
node1    HardwareType       IB-1050-A
node2    HardwareType       IB-550-A
node3    HardwareType       IB-550-A
node4    HardwareType       IB-550-A
node5    HardwareType       IB-1050-A
node6    HardwareType       IB-1410
```

I would like to modify the table to be like:

```
Node Name   Temp    NiosVersion HardwareType
Node1       +27.20  6.5.2       IB-1050-A
Node2       +27     6.5.2       IB-550-A
Node3       +26.50  6.5.2       IN-550-A
.
.
.
```

What would be the best way to change to this format?  Would I CREATE a VIEW out of the initial query and make a new SELECT FROM WHERE statements?

I am not sure how to take a field like “HardwareType” and make it a column named Hardware Type and place the corresponding STATUS value to a different column.  It seems like some sort of conditional is required like CASE.

Any ideas to point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Comment: what rdbms are you using?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `CASE` here and perform an aggregation (like `MIN` or `MAX`):

```
SELECT  NODENAME,
        MIN(CASE WHEN MIB = 'CPUTemperature' THEN Status END) AS Temp,
        MIN(CASE WHEN MIB = 'NiosVersion' THEN Status END) AS NiosVersion,
        MIN(CASE WHEN MIB = 'HardwareType' THEN Status END) AS HardwareType
FROM (...Your Query Here...) Data
GROUP BY NODENAME
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I would do:

```
SELECT a.nodename, 
       b.status AS 'Temp', 
       c.status AS 'NiosVersion', 
       d.status AS 'HardwareType' 
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT nodename 
        FROM   nodes) a 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT nodename, 
                         status 
                  FROM   nodes 
                  WHERE  mib = 'CPUTemperature') b 
              ON b.nodename = a.nodename 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT nodename, 
                         status 
                  FROM   nodes 
                  WHERE  mib = 'NiosVersion') c 
              ON c.nodename = a.nodename 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT nodename, 
                         status 
                  FROM   nodes 
                  WHERE  mib = 'HardwareType') d 
              ON d.nodename = a.nodename
```

**Result**

```
| NODENAME |     TEMP | NIOSVERSION | HARDWARETYPE |
----------------------------------------------------
|    node1 | +27.20 C |       6.5.2 |    IB-1050-A |
|    node2 | +27.00 C |       6.5.2 |     IB-550-A |
|    node3 | +26.50 C |       6.5.2 |     IB-550-A |
|    node4 | +27.00 C |       6.5.2 |     IB-550-A |
|    node5 | +27.80 C |       6.5.2 |    IB-1050-A |
|    node6 |   (null) |       6.5.2 |      IB-1410 |
```

### [See a demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/006d0/4)

Comment: It appears there are a variety of ways to implement this.  Thanks for your input everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your RDBMS that you are using, this would be done with a `PIVOT` function. Both SQL Server 2005+ and Oracle 11g+ have this function.

The query would be:

```
select *
from
(
  select nodename, MIB, status
  from yourtable
) src
pivot
(
  max(status)
  for mib in (CPUTemperature, NiosVersion, HardwareType)
) piv
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d9648/1)

Comment: You aren't kidding about liking `pivot` questions.

Comment: @njk they are my favorite questions to answer.